# Can I use a SQL case to choose the Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying this and getting an error.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM
        CASE @Type
            WHEN 'UserName' THEN Users WHERE UserName = @Name;                              
            WHEN 'UserGroup' THEN Groups Where GroupName = @GroupName AND GroupType = 'USERGROUP'
        END
```

I know you generally use case after an '=' sign ... but is there a way to do what I am trying here?

sql server 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either write dynamic SQL and execute that, or us an IF statement and two queries...

```
IF (@type = 'UserName')
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE UserName = @name
ELSE IF (@type = 'UserGroup')
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Groups WHERE GroupName = @GroupName AND GroupType = 'USERGROUP'
```

Comment: I typed the letters IF three times, you owe me two more up votes ;) Wait I did it again, that's three more up votes now!

Comment: Thanks ... Only thing is, I have about 5 options and was thinking the CASE statement might look nicer.  But it seems unavoidable to have to use the IF

Comment: It's the difference between a compiled statement, or dynamic sql.  You couldn't (for example) write this in many languages...  x = x {if (sign == -1) - else +;} 1;

Answer (score 1):

**Nope.**

The only way to change your fields, tables, or database dynamically in a query is to use [Dyanmic SQL.](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)  It's a dangerous thing though, so tread carefully.